# Where can I view SQL Server system functions in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

In SSMS I can view available system functions in the Object Explorer under the folder `Programability > Functions > Systems Functions`. I don't see that folder in my installation of Visual Studio 2019. I have SSDT installed and the SQL Server Object Explorer view open.

Comment: You can't see them in the same way, but if you write a SQL statement in a script / view or stored procedure you can use SELECT CTRL+SPACE will give a scrollable list of sytem variables and system functions e.g. @@connections or ABS etc.

Comment: CTL SPACE isn't working for me, although it shows as assigned to Edit.CompleteWord (Ctrl_Space(Text Editor)) in Tools>Options>Keyboard

Comment: Do you have intellisense enabled in VS - Tools -> Options -> Environment-> Text Editor -> SQL Server Tools. Then in General settings you have statement completion - autolist members & in Intellisense you have enable?

Comment: Sorry, Steve, I didn't note that you specified SELECT CTL SPACE. That does work.